# Get groups of rows which have more than 2 columns same

Tags: mysql

```
    Name        Class ID            Joining date     First payment
1    ABCD        710091            17/08/2019       500
2   ABCD        7100091            17/08/2019       500
3   DEFG        710092            18/08/2019       600
4    DEFG        710092            18/08/2019       6000
```

In the above example 2 can be a duplicate entry of 1 (class id is the only item different)
and 4 can be a duplicate entry of 3
i need to group rows with more than 2 column are same

expected output
group 1

```
1    ABCD        710091            17/08/2019       500
2   ABCD        7100091            17/08/2019       50
```

group 2

```
3   DEFG        710092            18/08/2019       600
4    DEFG        710092            18/08/2019       6000
```

Comment: Which columns are actually being targeted here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output you expect from your sample input.

Comment: Provide your data sample as (complete) CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Count the differences. If 1, then the pair is a candidate duplicate.